# How can I add "synonyms" to a <select> element's <option> for the browser's AutoFill?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autofill

I am trying to make an address form that forces a specific format (for the back-end), looks good (for the user) and is simple to fill out (autofill support) but I'm not having much luck with the `<select>` element's AutoFilling in Safari (our most popular browser).

I'm using a `<select>` element for the different Australian states, so that the format stays consistent. I also prefer it showing as "New South Wales" while value being "NSW" e.g `<option value="NSW">New South Wales</option>`

```html
<form>
  <input autocomplete="address-line1" maxlength="50" name="address-line1" placeholder="Line 1" type="text">
  <input autocomplete="address-line2" maxlength="50" name="address-line2" placeholder="Line 2" type="text">
  <input autocomplete="address-level2" maxlength="50" name="city" placeholder="Perth" type="text">
  <input autocomplete="postal-code" maxlength="10" name="postal_code" placeholder="6000" type="text">
  <select autocomplete="address-level1" name="state" required="">
    <option disabled selected="" value="">—</option>
    <option value="ACT">Australian Capital Territory</option>
    <option value="NSW">New South Wales</option>
    <option value="NT">Northern Territory</option>
    <option value="QLD">Queensland</option>
    <option value="SA">South Australia</option>
    <option value="TAS">Tasmania</option>
    <option value="VIC">Victoria</option>
    <option value="WA">Western Australia</option>
  </select>
  <select autocomplete="country" name="country" required="">
    <option value="AU" selected="">Australia</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1r5jsmtp/

The problem is, when I show the user non-abbreviated state names, the state field will only autofill if they've also set their AutoFill address to be the non-abbreviated state name and vice versa.

I want it to AutoFill regardless of whether they've set "New South Wales" or "NSW" in their AutoFill preferences.

I've tried setting the option label `<option label="">` but still experience the same issue.

[image]

How can I set "synonyms" for the AutoFill to catch on to, so that it selects the right option automatically?

Comment: The Shopify checkout has solved this issue via javascript somehow.. Not too sure what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the right answer, but I have an alternative answer.

### Use an input with a datalist

You can switch your select statement to being an `input` and use the `list` attribute to point to a datalist. The datalist will have all your options. The autocomplete should still work. My only concern would be testing for the proper address on the back end.

```html
<input list=options autocomplete="address-level1" name="state" placeholder="State" required="">
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="ACT">Australian Capital Territory</option>
  <option value="NSW">New South Wales</option>
  <option value="NT">Northern Territory</option>
  <option value="QLD">Queensland</option>
  <option value="SA">South Australia</option>
  <option value="TAS">Tasmania</option>
  <option value="VIC">Victoria</option>
  <option value="WA">Western Australia</option>
</datalist>
```